# javascript textbox: enter text and it appears instantly in another textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox, getelementbyid

Javascripters, a 'puzzle':
Using a simple HTML form, make two textboxes. Whatever text you type (say, some random string of characters like *asdfasdf* ) into textbox #1 is **IMMEDIATELY** displayed, on the fly, without pressing any button or changing focus, into textbox #2.
Can it be done using `getElementByID`?

Comment: Depending on your definition of *immediately*, this may or may not be possible.

Comment: @Anurag Since the word is both in caps and in bold, I suspect the immediacy must happen on the sub-atomic level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
<textarea id="text1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('text2').value = this.value"></textarea>
<textarea id="text2" onkeyup="document.getElementById('text1').value = this.value"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

If immediately is the most important word, you must handle the `keypress` event, then add the pressed key to your storage string. Then place that string into your result div or textarea.